# View dependencies of a table type in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, dependencies

How to view the dependency of a table type in SQL Server? For example, I have a stored procedure, and inside that stored procedure I use a table type.

I used the following to find dependency for table/SP

```
SELECT    referencing_schema_name, referencing_entity_name, referencing_id, referencing_class_desc, is_caller_dependent
FROM      sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('dbo.tablename', 'OBJECT');

SELECT    referenced_schema_name, referenced_entity_name, referenced_minor_name, referenced_minor_id, referenced_class_desc
FROM      sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities ('dbo.tablename', 'OBJECT');
```

But this will not work for table type.

Comment: Did you try changing `'OBJECT'` to `'TYPE'`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand You are right! Thanks. Just realize that only `sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities` has `TYPE`, the `sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities` does not. If you post the above comment as answer I'll accept it.

Comment: in second select statement if you change the **'dbo.tablename'** argument to the name of stored procedure you'll see all the dependencies of the stored procedure